# Corona sdk physics doesn't work

Tags: mobile, sdk, lua, coronasdk, physics

I have problem with implementing physics into my code.

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()


local safe = display.newImageRect("safe.png",100,100)
safe.x=display.contentCenterX+80

safe.y=display.contentCenterY

safe.height=100

safe.width=100

physics.addBody( safe, { density=1.0, friction=1 } )
```

Nothing happens, my image is on fixed position and doesn't move at all. Does any one have any ideas what should I do to make that code work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you have to add an object to physics,

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

physics.setGravity( 0, 6 )


physics.addBody( safe, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
```

Comment: "static" objects don't move. You need the object to either be "dynamic" on "kinematic" to be affected by gravity and fall.